# How to mock file upload in testcafe

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am writing an e2e test for file upload. Testcafe has an API `setFilesToUpload` which takes a selector and file path as arguments. The problem is the file size which is a bit large for `.apk, .ipa`. Is there a way to mock these files. I don't think it's a good idea to put MBs file just for the e2e test.

**Testcafe Api:**

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const uploadBtn = Selector('#upload-button');

fixture `My fixture`
.page `http://www.example.com/`;

test('Trying to upload with no files specified', async t => {
await t
    .setFilesToUpload('#upload-input', [
        './uploads/1.jpg',
        './uploads/2.jpg',
        './uploads/3.jpg'
    ])
    .clearUpload('#upload-input')
    .expect(uploadBtn.visible).notOk();
});
```

See if you find something relevant.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "way to mock these files". Where should these files be mocked? Maybe you can create a minimal size "hello world" `.apk, .ipa` for testing purposes.

Comment: in the same folder. yeah that could be possibe